# Negative Magnetoresistance from Frozen-Out Spin-Flip Scattering

Tags: solid-state-physics, electrical-resistance, scattering

A free electron gas would have zero magnetoresistance; it takes two carrier types to get ordinary magnetoresistance, which is always positive in sign.

[Beal-Monod and Weiner](http://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.170.552) explain the negative magnetoresistance found in very dilute magnetic alloys, in terms of the spin-flip scattering of conduction electrons off the impurities.

Their argument seems to be the following.

Consider the case where $\mu_BH<k_BT$.

A conduction electron in initial state $|\vec{k_i},\downarrow\rangle$ scatters off of an impurity with spin component $M_s$ into the final state $|\vec{k_f},\uparrow\rangle$ (and the impurity will have spin component $M_s-1$.  If energy is conserved, $|\vec{k_f}|=|\vec{k_i}|$.  The net change in energy will be $-2\mu_BH$.

Now, only states within $k_BT$ of the Fermi Level participate in scattering processes, so the energy of this new state will be, at most, $\epsilon_F+k_BT-2\mu_BH$.  It seems like I must have made some sort of mistake here, as the new state will have energy between $\epsilon_F+k_BT$ and $\epsilon_F-k_BT$, which is allowed by the Pauli principle.  They argue that "the final-state spin-up electron has a total energy (kinetic+Zeeman) less than $\epsilon_F$ by at least $2\mu_BH-k_BT$ and this scattering process is forbidden by the exclusion principle."  **What am I misunderstanding here?**  Their result seems to match mine, and it seems to allow for scattering into perfectly allowed states.

The second half of the argument is that since the applied field, $H$ tends to *align the impurties with the field*, there will be more scattering processes like the ones described above ($\downarrow\to\uparrow$) than the opposite ($\uparrow\to\downarrow$).  Why is that?

Is it because there is a reduction of the number of impurities in the state with the lowest possible angular momentum? (i.e. if $S_\text{min}\leq M_s\leq S_\text{max}$, there will be fewer impurities with $M_s=S_\text{min}$ than $M_s=S_\text{max}$).

Can anyone fill in the confusion here? Thanks!